# Coffeescript setInterval in class

Tags: coffeescript, setinterval

I started writing coffeescript last week, as I am programming a new Play20 site where coffeescript is the standard. I want to update a getData function in my class every 5 minutes, but the setInterval function does not bind to my class. Only the first time it calls getData, because the 'this' object is still reachable, as the setUpdateInterval() function is called from within the constructor.

But after the first call, the setInterval does not have any connection anymore with the Widget instance, and does not know what the this.getData() function is (and how to reach it).

Does someone know how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
class Widget
  constructor: (@name) ->
    this.setUpdateInterval()

  getData: ->
    console.log "get Data by Ajax"

  setUpdateInterval: (widget) ->
    setInterval( this.getData(), 3000000 )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now here some Javascript magic is required. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout)

```
class Widget
  constructor: (@name) ->
    this.setUpdateInterval()

  getData: ->
    console.log "get Data by Ajax"

  setUpdateInterval: (widget) ->
    callback = @getData.bind(this)
    setInterval( callback, 3000000 )
```

This will work in almost all browsers (guess which one not), so the
function will have to be bound differently. Some coffeescript magic:

```
callback = => @getData
```

Comment: you can do your bind call like `cb = @getData.bind @`, and you also don't need the parenthesis on the `setInterval` line...more coffee.  +1, I might like this answer better than mine, except for the fact that it won't work in IE.

Comment: Thanks, the code does exactly what I wanted it do to (in Chrome)! 
One thing the 'callback = -> that.getData.call(that)' seems not to compile.

One next question, by bounding differtly do you mean that I need two bindings, one for all browsers except IE and one special for IE or do I need just the last binding?

Comment: @Tass sure, but it's not coffeescript-esque ;)

Comment: Use fat arrow (bound instance method) see my solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are executing the function, instead of passing a reference to it.

Now, it sounds like you need to also keep the scope of the instance.  `do` and `=>` can help with that.

```
 setUpdateInterval: (widget) ->
    setInterval (do =>
      @getData), 3000000
    true
```

compiles to

```
Widget.prototype.setUpdateInterval = function(widget) {
      var _this = this;
      setInterval((function() {
        return _this.getData;
      })(), 3000000);
      return true;
    };
```

you will note the code executes a self invoking function, which return a function, that creates a closure around `this`, locking it into the scope of the callback (as `_this`)

Also note that you don't need to pass widget to the method (you aren't using it anywhere), and you would invoke this function in your constructor, to set up the interval.  Whatever you do, you only want to call this method once.  You could just put the contents of the function in your constructor.

Finally, since coffeescript returns the value of the last statement from all functions, I throw a `true` in there, but that might no be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is handy in node as well. It's a varient of Tass's answer.

```
class Widget
  constructor: (@options = {}) ->
    @options.interval ?= 1000
    @setInterval()

  timer: ->
    console.log 'do something'

  setInterval: ->
    cb = @timer.bind @
    setInterval cb, @options.interval

w = new Widget()
```